# Constraint with setter methods to be used in other generic types

Tags: go, generics

I'm playing with golang generics, trying to implement CRUD operations over all the mongo collections, but I'm facing issues trying to update some fields directly on the struct but I'm getting an error

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TModel interface {
    MyUser | AnotherModel
    SetName(string)
}

type MyUser struct {
    ID   string `bson:"_id"`
    Name string `bson:"name"`
}

type AnotherModel struct {
    ID   string `bson:"_id"`
    Name string `bson:"name"`
}

// Using this function compiles, but never update the struct
func (s MyUser) SetName(name string) {
    s.Name = name
}

/*This should be the right way, but fails at compile time */
/*
func (s *MyUser) SetName(name string) {
    s.Name = name
}
*/

type Crud[model TModel] interface {
    UpdateObj(m model) (*model, error)
}

type CrudOperations[model TModel] struct {
}

func (c *CrudOperations[model]) UpdateObj(m model) error {
    fmt.Printf("\n  Obj: %v", m)
    m.SetName("NewName")
    fmt.Printf("\n  Obj: %v", m)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    c := CrudOperations[MyUser]{}
    m := MyUser{Name: "Initial-Name"}
    c.UpdateObj(m)

}
```

---

./prog.go:44:22: MyUser does not implement TModel (SetName method has pointer receiver)

I tried changing from `func(s *MyUser)` to `func (s MyUser)` but then the struct is not reflecting the change

```
ineffective assignment to field MyUser.Name (staticcheck)
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/GqKmu_JfVtC

Comment: `method SetName has pointer receiver` This is not the complete error message. It is just a hint. The actual "error" part of the message is what you need to look into.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it here the reproducible example
https://go.dev/play/p/GqKmu_JfVtC
I left the function without pointer receiver (compile but does not update the struct) and the *right* way but it fails at compile

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791637/cannot-use-variable-of-type-t-as-type-in-argument/71793077#71793077), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573113/how-can-i-instantiate-a-non-nil-pointer-of-type-argument-with-generic-go) especially for cases where just mutating the function argument is not enough, and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71376627/in-go-generics-how-to-use-a-common-method-for-types-in-a-union-constraint) for the general use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a type constaint :

```
type TModel interface {
    MyUser | AnotherModel
    ...
```

in your interface, so you can't use a `*MyUser` as a type parameter for `TModel`

---

To fix your compile time error : change the type constraint

```
type TModel interface {
    *MyUser | *AnotherModel
    ...
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/1oP2LzeqXIa

---

one extra remark : unless you have an ulterior motive to explicitly list the only types that can ever be used as a `TModel`, I would say that

```
type TModel interface {
    SetName(s string)
}
```

is probably enough of a constraint for your generic type.